# How to scale a value down?

Tags: math, scaling

I have a variable `x` that accepts a range of values from 0 - 500.

I want to represdnt this variable's value in a new variable `xScaled` that accepts a range of 0 - 1.

**Example:** 
*Given `x = 292` what is the relative value of `xScaled` and how can this be calculated?*

Thanks

Comment: It *is* a real question, it's just offtopic. Regardless, it's trivial enough that it's easier to answer than to close.

Comment: @Blindy Its a prefectly valid math question. Just because I havent decalred variables in programing terms doesnt make it "off topic" in my opinion.

Comment: Actually it does, there is a math stackoverflow site. But in case you haven't noticed, I'm defending your question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just divide by 500:

```
xScaled = 292/500;
```

Answer (score 4):

You *seem* to be asking for the formula:

```
xScaled = x / 500
```

For a more general solution, the following pseudo-code can map one range to another:

```
def mapRange (x, from_min, from_max, to_min, to_max):
    return (x - from_min) * (to_max - to_min) / (from_max - from_min) + to_min
```

Answer (score 2):

Divide by the maximum value: (0-500) becomes (0/500-500/500)=(0-1).

So for 292, scaled it becomes 292/500.

Answer (score 1):

In C and similar languages:

```
x = 292;
xScaled = x / 500.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

No offence intended, but this is fairly simple arithmetics. Your programming skills will *greatly* improve if you spend just few minutes a day here: http://www.khanacademy.org/